# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Siswa>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a two error for this Flutter apps.

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

> The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

When I add ('!') or null check, new error showed up.

> The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.

Here's the code :

```
list() {
return Expanded(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: siswa,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return dataTable(snapshot.data);
      }
      if (null == snapshot.data || snapshot.data!.length == 0) {
        return const Text("");
      }
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
);
```

}

And here's the full code on my GitHub : https://github.com/kisekifrans/pencatat_nama_mahasiswa

Thank you for the attention and have a wonderful day everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your `snapshot.data` type is not defined, so it is taken as an `Object?`. This causes the errors.

What can you do:

- Use cast like `(snapshot.data as List<Siswa>).length`
- And better option - add cast directly to your builder. Just add at `<type>` the end of your `FutureBuilder`. In your case it will be like `FutureBuilder<List<Siswa>>` and so your `snapshot.data` will be identified as List

You can use such cast in many different cases, like casting types of your iterable:

- `List<String>` can contain only `String` values
- `Map<String, dynamic>` can only get `String` values as key, but the value can implement any type (that is what `dynamic` means)

More about casting you can read here https://itnext.io/flutter-methodchannel-dart-generic-and-type-casting-54ca48e6d3ad

Okay, lets look firstly on `src/siswa.dart`:

```
class Siswa {
  late int id;
  late String nama;
  late int nim;

  Siswa(this.id, this.nama, this.nim);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'nama': nama,
      'nim': nim,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Siswa.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    nama = map['nama'];
    nim = map['nim'];
  }
}
```

All it's parameters has type and can not be null. Look at `main.dart` at line 64:

```
Siswa e = Siswa(null, nama, nim);
```

You apply `null` to `int` type. You can:

- make `id` field nullable (`late int? id;`)
- Send `int` instead of `null` (`Siswa e = Siswa(0, nama, nim);`)

---

```
Text(siswa.nim),
```

Here you trying to print `int` through `Text` widget. But `Text` widget applies only `String` type, so you should do like this:

```
Text(siswa.nim.toString()),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It works *really well*. 

But I still have 3 **errors** left, it is 

 - The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type
   'int'.
 - The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type
   'String'.
 - A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type
   'String'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
   right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: All this errors are caused by incorrect casting. You should understand, that casting is very important, expecially when you making https requests. And yep, I found some errors in ur code, wait, I'll write new answer